# Search for folder and file

Tags: powershell

I have a script to develop in PowerShell to search folder "setup bootstrap" in C: and in that search particular keyword

```
Final result:                  Passed

Start time:                    2017-07-03 04:38:24
End time:                      2017-07-03 04:42:45
```

in that summary.txt file.

I have written something like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem C:\program* -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and
    $_.Name -match "setup bootstrap"
}
```

I am getting both x86 as well as 64.

There is query running for SQL Server for getting 64bit or 86 bit

```sql
select SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as Version,
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as service_pack,
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as Edition,
    SERVERPROPERTY('collation') as Collation
go
```

My question is how to search in PowerShell as program* gives me both 86 as well as 64 bit version and after finding "setup bootstrap" I have to search in summary.txt for

```
Final result: Passed

Start time:                    2017-07-03 04:38:24
End time:                      2017-07-03 04:42:45
```

at this particular time interval.
Can you please help me out?

Comment: Do you have a folder "setup bootstrap" in "C:\Program Files" and "C:\Program Files (x86)"? Why? And which of them would you want to process? Where does the SQL come from? And how does the time interval come into play?

Comment: Angsar thanks for check my question, yes folder exists in both folders x86 as well, iam not sure why but but setbootstrap has only bin folder in 64 bit inside log where summary.txt need to check C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log i

Comment: how to search folder with space Get-ChildItem C:\program* -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and
    $_.Name -match "setup bootstrap"

Comment: If you're looking for a file `summary.txt` anyway, I'd do something like `Get-ChildItem C:\Programs* -Include 'summary.txt' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -like '*\setup bootstrap\*' }`. That doesn't answer my other questions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$_.Name -match` you should use `-Filter` with the gci.
It's not clear to me what you want to do with summary.txt content.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files*' -Recurse -Filter '*setup bootstrap*' -EA silentlycontinue|
  Where-Object PSIsContainer|
    ForEach-Object {
      Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Filter 'summary.txt' | 
        Select-String -Pattern '^Final result:\s+(.+)$'|
          ForEach-Object {$_.matches.captures.value}
    }
```

Comment: in summary.txt i have to search keyword Final result: Passed as iam developing script for silent installation of sp service pack on sql server . SO if i found that keyword that means sp upgrade is sucessful

Comment: It's still unclear to me what the final outcome of the script should be:

Comment: Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\*' -recurse |
 Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "setup bootstrap"}

Comment: now iam getting only 1 folder in above command i want to search text passed in summary.txt can you please help me out

Comment: final outcome should be if its passed it should as passed or failed after searching in summary.txt

Comment: summary.txt is inside setup bootstrap folder , hope iam clear now

Comment: Try changed script.

Comment: Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "PSIsCo
ntainer" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.Sc
riptBlock".
At line:2 char:15
+   Where-Object <<<<  PSIsContainer|
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBi
   ndingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerSh
   ell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: some error lotpings thanks for trying really appreciate

Comment: There seems to be an erroneous space in `PSIsContainer` in **your** code.